# How to Trigger Animations on Scroll with Waypoints.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-waypoints, inview

I've been trying to figure out how to trigger animations on scroll, and I can't quite get it. Basically, I want to have a class that I can add to my titles that will trigger an animation any time the element with the class is scrolled into view.

I tried using the jQuery [Inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) plugin, but I couldn't get it to do what I wanted. Then I switched to [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) and I kind of have it working, but it's not perfect. Right now, the elements animate when I scroll to them for the first time but they do nothing when I scroll up and back down the page. The animations only fire once.

Below is my current code. If anyone can help me figure out a way to get the animations triggering every time the user scrolls past them—and also a way to condense the code so that it fires based on class and not ID—that would be really excellent. (Right now, I have separate function for each element.)

PS: I'm using [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/), [textillate.js](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/) for the animations.

HTML

```
<h1 class="lettering wow fadeInDown" id="l1" data-in-effect="flipInY">Yo. Check it out.</h1>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
var l1 = $("#l1");
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('l1'),
  handler: function() {
      l1.textillate({ in: { effect: 'flipInY' } });
  },
  offset: 'bottom-in-view',
});
});
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** I have found a partial solution that triggers the animations every time you scroll past them. However, I can only seem to get it to work with `ids`. I'd rather be able to target a `class` than have to write a separate function for each new title. Any ideas on how to modify the following code so that it works for a class of `.lettering`?

```
// Animate #l1
$(function () {
var animatel1 = $('#l1').textillate({ 
    autoStart: false,
    in: { effect: 'flipInY' },
    out: { effect: 'fadeOut', sync: true, }
});

var l1 = $("#l1");
var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
  element: $('#l1'),
  enter: function(direction) {
  },
  entered: function(direction) {
    animatel1.textillate('in')
  },
  exit: function(direction) {
    animatel1.textillate('out')
  },
  exited: function(direction) {
  }
})  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Having it work with a class is a matter of looping through your array of elements. I see you're using jQuery, so it can help you with a bit of the boilerplate:

```
$(function () {
  $('.your-class').textillate({ 
      autoStart: false,
      in: { effect: 'flipInY' },
      out: { effect: 'fadeOut', sync: true, }
  });

  $('.your-class').each(function() {
    new Waypoint.Inview({
      element: this,
      entered: function(direction) {
        $(this.element).textillate('in')
      },
      exit: function(direction) {
        $(this.element).textillate('out')
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Needed to wrap everything in an `.each()` function. Replace `lettering` with your class name and you should be good to go.

```
  $('.lettering').each(function() {
    var animatelettering = $('.lettering').each(function(){
        $(this).textillate({ 
            autoStart: false,
            in: { effect: 'flipInY' },
            out: { effect: 'fadeOut', sync: true, }
        });
    });
    new Waypoint.Inview({
      element: this,
      enter: function(direction) {
      },
      entered: function(direction) {
        animatelettering.textillate('in')
      },
      exit: function(direction) {
        animatelettering.textillate('out')
      },
      exited: function(direction) {
      }
    });
  });
```